# Find and replace regex JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex, url, replace

I know this is a super easy question, but I can't seem to wrap my head about it. I've got a bunch of URLs in varying languages such as:

www.myurl.com?lang=spa

www.myurl.com?lang=deu

www.myurl.com?lang=por

I need to create buttons to quickly switch from any language extension (spa, por, deu, rus, ukr, etc) to another language. I have the following code so far:

```
var url = window.location.toString();
window.location = url.replace(/lang=xxx/, 'lang=deu');
```

I just can't figure out the 3-character wildcard character. I know that I need to do some sort of regular expression or something, I'm just not sure how to go about it. Any help?

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Answer (score 1):

Try `...` or `.{3}` or `\w{3}` or even `[a-z]{3}`, depending on how specific you want to be.

```javascript
var s = 'www.myurl.com?lang=spa';
s.replace(/lang=[a-z]{3}/, 'lang=deu');
// => "www.myurl.com?lang=deu"
```

Here's a [railroad diagram](http://regexper.com/#lang%3D%5Ba-z%5D%7B3%7D) of the above example:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
([&?]lang=)\w+
```

This will work with urls like `www.myurl.com?foo=bar&lang=por&bar=foo` too.

Instead of `lang=deu`, you'll have to replace with `$1deu`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `/lang=[a-z][3}/`, here's an example:

```
/lang=[a-z]{3}/
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/hRunVP3I_r8SiVw4)